# Sending data from a component to a service file in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an
*app.component.html*

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="keystroke">
{{keystroke}} <!-- prints out each keystroke -->
```

And an *app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
  keystroke = '';
}
```

This successfully prints out every keystroke value I enter into my searchbox.

However, I am trying to send the value of *keystroke* to the **getResults()** function in my ***task.service.ts*** (the code below) so that I can use the keystroke value for an api call.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class TaskService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log("Task service initialized...");
  }
  //get our result for each keystroke, return it as an observable (json)
  getResults() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/KEYSTROKES')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to do this. In *app.component.html* I could just use *{{keystroke}}*, but referencing the keystroke value in my *task.service.ts* does not seem to be as simple.

How can I send my keystroke data to my *task.service.ts*, so that I can run my api call?

Also, I am trying to create an Angular 2 app the "right way", so all critiques are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind an event handler to your input

```
<input (ngModelChange)="getResults($event)" ...>
```

Or

```
<input (keyup)="getResults($event)" ...>
```

See
https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-the-event-object

Comment: Thanks for the comment! How would I define getResults in the html? I currently have ```<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="keystroke" (ngModelChange)="getResults($event)">``` but when I run this, getResults is just undefined.

Comment: Oh getResults() would need to be in your @Component, (and the event handler should be renamed to onKeyUp()). This would then call your service.